# Running PHP script constantly in background

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have created a PHP file that contains an infinite loop that does certain checks and acts if variables change (what's inside the script is probably not very important for my question). I want the service to always run, untill I tell it to stop. After some searching I decided to be using `nohup` for this task. However, the downside of nohup is that I can't really monitor if the service is down (other than manually running `ps -aux` and looking for the process).

I've also read things about `supervisord`, which also sounded pretty good, but I'm kind of lost and don't really know what the best solution is. I want the PHP script to automatically start on reboots and I want the service to check if the script is still running, if not, I want it to reboot/alert so I can check what's up.

Should I be using either `nohup` or `supervisord`? Or do you guys recommend something totally different? It would be great if I could run the service inside a docker container where I can simply add the execution of the service inside the `Dockerfile`.

Comment: What's wrong with creating a systemd unit?

Comment: the Docker container would already do what you want, you answered your own question.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider how does a docker container already do that? Does a docker container create a service of the php command it executes? And I'll look into systemd, is it any different than supervisord?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're better off just using good'ol CRON.

You can configure any script to run at whatever interval though I would not recommend running it continuously, maybe have it run every 5 minutes. So something like this:

```
*/5 * * * * php /path/to/php/file >/dev/null 2>&1
```

So you can learn more about CRON: https://linuxman.co/linux-server/cron-a-nosedive-into-lazy-sysadmin/